# php: Why cann't I insert into my db?

Tags: php, sql, database, insert

First of all, I am not getting any errors but it still doesn't work.
I simply want to insert in my table... I've also tryed

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO Rangliste2 (name, score) VALUES ('$text', $zahl)");
```

before, with the same, unsatisfying result.

```
<?php>
// score speichern
$zahl = $_POST["text2"];

// name speichern
$text = $_POST["text1"];
if($text == null){
    echo("Keinen Text empfangen.");
} 


// verbindung zu db herstellen
$db = @new mysqli("...", "...", "...", "...");
if($db->connect_error){
    die("<pre>".$db->connect_error."</pre>");
}

$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO Rangliste2 (name, score) VALUES ('$text', $zahl)");

//sql abfrage
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rangliste2 ORDER BY score DESC");
$num = $sql->num_rows; // anzahl der Datensätze
if($num > 0){
    while($row = $sql->fetch_object()){
        echo ("$row->name:       $row->score\n");
    }
}
?>
```

When I look at my db table, nothing has been inserted...
I appreciate every answer !

Comment: did u try to `var_dump($_POST);` to see if u getting any values, and check this `VALUES ( '$text', $zahl )` u missing `' '` on other variable

Comment: You should remove all `@` characters (like when you create the db connection) since that character _suppresses errors_ and will fail silently. Handle errors correctly instead and it will be easier to debug the code.

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really **use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Have you checked the servers error log for potential error messages?

Comment: I used the same code for my first table where it works perfectly fine... yeah I know, a child with a calculator can hack my script, but I want it to work before I care about that

Comment: **Never** wait with writing secure code. **1**. You _will_ forget/miss/don't have time later and some insecure code will make it to production. **2**. You need to rewrite it all, so it will when using prepared statements and you will get _new_ bugs. **3**. Going back and rewrite your code takes longer than doing it correctly from the start.. **4**. It's not all about security, currently, if any value contains a  `'` character, your code will break. **5**. When rewriting it to use Prepared Statements, you might actually solve your current errors.